# How to Group by timestamp for each day in pandas dataframe and write it to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, timestamp

I have a .csv-file with alot of data. It's data that have been collected every 10 minutes, so the timestamp (column is named 'TIMESTAMP') is in this format: DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm. I want to create/write a new csv file for *each day* of data using pandas in python.

This code creates a new csv file for every 10 minutes (so now I have a lot of files lol):

```
for name, group in df.groupby('TIMESTAMP'):
    group.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(name), index=False)
```

Is groupby even a good solution to this? I was thinking of doing some kind of loop and if-statement, but groupby seemed like a good and lazy solution...

Really appreciate all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groupby is a good solution. I would create a column where you round your datetime to single days and group on this column:

```
df['day']=df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.floor('d')

for name, group in df.groupby('day'):
    group.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(name), index=False)
```

**Edit**

If don't want to change the columns of your dataframe you just have to drop the new column before saving it to csv:

```
for name, group in df.groupby('day'):
    group.drop('day',axis=1).to_csv('{}.csv'.format(name), index=False)
```

Comment: That looks great, thanks for your input. But I really don't want to add any columns to the df since it's supposed to match already existing data...

Comment: that's an easy fix, you only have to drop the new column before saving it. I edited the answer, have a look at it.